# Is there a setting that allows LinkedIn to "forget" my email contact list?

Tags: linkedin, contacts, android

The last time I logged in to the LinkedIn app on my Android smartphone, the app asked me to read info from my email contacts to suggest me people I know that are registered in LinkedIn.

Now I would like to prevent the LinkedIn app from continuing to use this information from my contacts but I am not able to find this setting.

Comment: Since this has to do with a general LinkedIn feature and not something specific to the web application, I think it's okay here.

Comment: It would be interesting to understand why 2 users click -1 to this question. It was a real problem to me since this solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to info from [LinkedIn's Help Center](http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/49/~/removing-a-connection): "It's not possible to remove a connection from a mobile device."

Here is the content they share related to your issue:

> To remove a connection from the desktop:
>
> - Go to the connection's profile.
> - Move your cursor over the  Arrow
>     icon next to the button in the top section of the profile. The button
>     name may vary.
> - Select Remove connection.
> - Review the list of
>     effects of removing the connection and click Remove.
>
> Note: If you don’t see Remove connection in the drop-down list, you
>   may need to refresh your connections. To do this, go to your
>   Connections page, click the Settings icon on the right, then click the
>   Refresh link next to LinkedIn.
>
> You can remove several connections at once on the Contacts page:
>
> - Move your cursor over Connections at the top of your homepage and
>     select Keep in Touch.
> - Click Filter by and select Connections Only.
> - Check the box next to the connections you'd like to remove.
> - Click
>     More above the first connection and select Remove from Contacts.
> - Review the list of effects of removing the connections and click
>     Remove.
>
> You can also remove individual connections from the Contacts page by
>   clicking More under their name and selecting Remove Connection.
>   Connections you remove will no longer be a 1st-degree connection and
>   will no longer appear in your Contacts section.
>
> - When you remove a connection, they won't be notified.
> - After
>     removing a connection, any recommendations or endorsements between you
>     and that person will be withdrawn. They will not be restored if the
>     connection is re-established.
> - Only the member who breaks the
>     connection can reinitiate that connection.

Find the original info source here: http://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/49/~/removing-a-connection